# Switch Statement based on Class Properties

Tags: c#, properties, switch-statement

I understand this is a rather confusing and weird thing to need to do, but is there any way to have a switch statement work based on the properties of an object. Like passing in an object's property, not the value of the property but the property itself, and having a switch evaluate?

The main goal is to have an object with a bunch of different properties and each property has conditions for whether the overall object is true or false, so I want to be able to call a single method from multiple places and have each place say which property it wants to be checked for T/F.

ex:

```
public class Foo{
  public int StuffsLimit{get;set;}
  public List<int> SomeList {get;set;}
}
...
switch(x){
  case Foo.StuffsLimit:
    //here, we check whether THIS condition is true
    return numberOfStuffs < StuffsLimit;    
  case Foo.SomeList:
    //here, we check if a different condition is true
    return SomeList.Contains(5);
}
```

im doing this to try to minimize extra/redundant code. The same property may need to be checked in multiple spots, so I want to avoid putting the actual check in those spots, but I also want to avoid using an Enum or individual methods for everything so that this will work dynamically as new properties get added to the original object.

Thank you

Comment: What exactly do want to switch on? When do you want `case Foo.StuffsLimit` evaluated; when StuffLimit is not null?

Comment: what is the `x` here?

Comment: note: C# 8 has flexible `when` contraints (including nested matching) - which *may* be what you're after, but it is hard to tell without knowing what the `x` is. Probably the best thing would be to write the code in "working, but long / ugly" C#, and we can see if it can be shortened.

Comment: The case has to be a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need some validation code. I would pass the validation method a `Foo` object together with the name of the property you want to validate.

```
public bool IsValid(Foo foo, string propertyName)
{
    switch(propertyName) {
        case nameof(Foo.StuffsLimit):
            return numberOfStuffs < foo.StuffsLimit;    
        case nameof(Foo.SomeList):
            return foo.SomeList.Contains(5);
        default:
            return false;
    }   
}
```

With the new C# 8.0 switch expression, and the expression bodied members you can simply it:

```
public bool IsValid(Foo foo, string propertyName) =>
    propertyName switch {
        nameof(Foo.StuffsLimit) => numberOfStuffs < foo.StuffsLimit,
        nameof(Foo.SomeList) => foo.SomeList.Contains(5),
        _ => false
    };
```

Note that `nameof(Foo.StuffsLimit)` is identical to `"StuffsLimit"`. The first variant is checked by the compiler and is subject to rename refactorings, the second is not. Of course you can use `nameof()` when calling this method: `if (!IsValid(foo, nameof(Foo.SomeList))) { ... }`

Comment: If this is the only solution then it will have to do. thanks for it though.
I never love relying in strings for things because IDEs dont spellcheck, so it can lead to very simple errors resulting in incredibly complex problems, all because i cant spel werds kerektlee

Comment: @Ilan_Schindler If you use nameof(Property) instead of hard coded strings you will avoid spelling errors and keep the ability to do rename refactoring, as Olivier mentioned in their last note.

Comment: `nameof(Property) ` is checked by the compiler. I.e., it does the spellcheck!

Answer (score 1):

This is an ideal case for some classic object-oriented polymorphism, which is another way of saying you want different behaviour for different types of object, when you don't know what type of object you have got, but you do know it inherits from a specific base class.

```
public class Foo
{
    public abstract bool Evaluate();
}

public class FooChildA : Foo
{
    public int StuffsLimit { get; set; }

    public override bool Evaluate()
    {
        return numberOfStuffs < StuffsLimit;
    }
}

public class FooChildB : Foo
{
    public List<int> SomeList { get; set; }

    public override bool Evaluate()
    {
        return SomeList.Contains(5);;
    }
}

// Somewhere later:

Foo foo = FooChildA();
// Calls FooChildA.Evaluate();
foo.Evaluate();
foo = FooChildB();
// Calls FooChildB.Evaluate();
foo.Evaluate();
```